# How to save a row in another table after a period of time in a Windows service

Tags: c#, sql-server-2005

I want to run my Windows service at 9:00AM to 9:00PM and after the 9:00PM my all rows need to be saved to another table only one time and last day of month all records will be deleted and last day records will be saved..... please help me my Window service is running at 9:00AM to 9:00PM......

Comment: You're not very clear - your NT Service writes rows into a table (what is that table called?? What does it look like?? Column names,  datatypes etc.). And then at 9PM, you want to write all rows written to that table during the day to a second table??

Comment: yes, i am saving record between 9:00 AM to 9:00 PM.. I want, after the 9:00PM my all records save to another table only one time in one day and last day of month all records will be deleted and last day records will be saved....

Comment: Are those rows that you insert during the day "discoverable" in some way, e.g. do they have the current day's date somewhere? Or how do you plan to find out which rows to copy from one table to the other at 9 PM ??

Answer (score 1):

You can use a timer that fires every minute. And between 9:00 AM to 9:00 PM you set a flag to tell where to save the records.

The code that is executed could set:

```
if(DateTime.Now.Hour < 9 && DateTime.Now.Hour > 21)
   TableToSaveTo = "secondTableToSaveTo";
else
   TableToSaveTo = "primaryTableToSaveTo"
```

Then you use the value in TableToSave to when you do the actual saves

Comment: yes, i am saving record between 9:00 AM to 9:00 PM.. I want, after the 9:00PM my all records save to another table only one time in one day and  last day of month all records will be deleted and last day records will be saved....

Comment: I ellaborated my answer a little bit

Comment: Thnks Mharlin, now how to delete all records to the last day of the month and only save the last day records of the month....

Comment: Check the value of TableToSave to and if it's being updated to a different value you can do some cleanup of the last days records then. If you think that I answered your question please set it as correct answer. If you accept answers you are more likely to get help with your questions